# Python, how to ensure object is garbage collected?

Tags: python, azure, garbage-collection, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have an api client instance needed for some work. I'll need to run several iterations of this work with a change in target directories each iteration.

Simple example. Obviously, the work we're doing is not just printing the client properties.

```
while x < y:

    SUB_DIR = f"dir_{x}"

    dir_client = AzDirectoryClient(
        file_system_name="my-container", 
        directory_name=SUB_DIR
    )
    
    print(dir_client.get_directory_properties())

    x += 1
```

The `dir_client` creation happens each iteration. There is no way to change the `directory_name` for an existing client as I understand it (Azure datalake gen2 python sdk, DataLakeDirectoryClient class).

Should each iteration delete the existing client (`del`) and create the new one? Will it be garbage collected if the name remains the same?

The number of iterations will be significant.

Comment: I added `def __del__(self):    print(f"Deleting {self}")` to the client class and it prints `Deleting <.... object at x123...>` each loop. So I guess that means each instance is garbage collected each loop and running this won't clog up the memory?

Comment: `Del` doesn't necessarily result in garbage collection, it just reduces the reference count on an object. If `del` reduces the reference count to 0, then the object will be destroyed (and memory freed) _the next time_ the garbage collector runs. Note that the garbage collector runs periodically in a non-deterministic way. Use [`gc.collect()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect) to force the garbage collector to run a collection.

Comment: Each time this code creates a new `AzDirectoryClient` and assigns it to `dir_client`, the previous `AzDirectoryClient` instance's reference count goes to 0 and the new `AzDirectoryClient`'s reference count is 1. The old instance will be garbage collected the next time the garbage collector runs, i.e. no need to `del` unless the actual code is creating more references to the instance.

Comment: @MichaelRuth Where did you get the idea that it needs a garbage collector run instead of being deleted immediately when the reference count becomes 0?

Comment: @KellyBundy, "When an object’s reference count reaches zero, the garbage collector may proceed to remove that object from memory" from https://realpython.com/python-del-statement/#unraveling-del-vs-garbage-collection. Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with discussion in the comments and below is my analysis:

Firstly I have created a object as below:

```
import gc

class Emooject:
    def __init__(self, peru):
        self.peru = peru
        print(f"Creating the object {self.peru}")
    def __del__(self):
        print(f"Deleting the object {self.peru}")
o = [Emooject("emo1")]
```

[image]

Then used `gc.collect` as below for forceful deletion:

```
import gc

class Emooject:
    def __init__(self, peru):
        self.peru = peru
        print(f"Creating the object {self.peru}")
    def __del__(self):
        print(f"Deleting the object {self.peru}")
o = [Emooject("emo2")]
gc.collect()
```

[image]

Automatic deletion without gc.collect():

[image]

I do agree with @Michael Ruth that whenever `dir_client = AzDirectoryClient()` this statement is called or executed new instance will be created and old will automatically deleted and if the code is creating more instances then use del .